# Aside from partial matching, can the $ operator do anything that [ and [[ cannot?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, dollar-sign

I believe the following to be true of the `$` operator:

- It allows names to be partially matched. For example, `data$Sky` can match `data$Skywalker` if there is no `Sky` name in use.
- It cannot be used for atomic vectors, unlike `[` and `[[`.
- It cannot be combine with operators like `-`. There is no valid syntax like `mtcars$-mpg`. `[` and `[[` cannot do this with names either, but `mtcars[,-1]` works.
- It is for names only.
- Partial matching aside, for a data frame, `data$name` is equivalent to `data[,"name"]` e.g. `mtcars$cyl` is the same as `mtcars[,"cyl"]`. I'm pretty sure that `data[["name"]]` is also equivalent, e.g. `mtcars[["cyl"]]`.
- Partial matching aside, for a named list that is not a data frame, `data$name` is the same as `data[["name"]]`.

Does this mean that if I don't care about partial matching, I can always replace `$` with `[` or `[[`? Or is there some functionality that I've missed?

Comment: You’re missing *readability*. `foo$bar` is slightly more readable than `foo[['bar']]`. It also makes static analysis easier. Apart from that I think your enumeration is complete (for builtin objects; since all these operators can be redefined, they’re not *generally* equivalent).

Comment: Even if you want partial matching, `[` allows a parameter `exact`which controls whether and how partial matching occurs.  `[` also allows more parametrs than `$`, including `drop`, and additional dimensions.  I must admit though, I have never come across anyone using the `exact` parameter in the wild.

Comment: I'd say you could have said that "you _should_  _always_ replace `$` with `[[` when building programs. The `$` operator is designed for console/interactive use, and failing to restrict its use to that purpose is a major cause of puzzling errors for persons trying to transition to effective programming with R

Comment: You may want to read https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: @IRTFM I strongly disagree with that: as I said in my first comment, your comment also ignores readability, and that’s an aspect that you shouldn’t neglect. `foo$bar` is plain more readable than `foo[['bar']]` (because it has a higher signal/noise ratio). The partial matching is annoying but can/should be turned into a warning via `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Please focus on the last three words of my suggestion. Many new R users assume that they can pass arguments delivered via the pairlist mechanism to code that uses '$'. You often see the error of  `fnew <- function(a=dfrm, cn=mycolname){ e <- a$cn}`. I did not say that users should stop using it to prototype at their console sessions or that they should stop using it in vignettes and blogs about data management and exploratory analyses.

Comment: Addendum: `$` is is clearly less flexible than "[[". You cannot do `a$cc` in my example but you can do `a[[cn]]`. Despite a$cc being readable to a human as to it's intent, that intent is not honored by R. In many ways it is the entire reason for the growth of first pkg;gglot and later the entire tidyverse.

Comment: @IRTFM  “$ is is clearly less flexible than "[[".” — Yes, and that’s a *good thing*. Flexibility introduces errors. Good APIs are rigid and disallow unwanted behaviour. You’re right that the distinction between names and values is something that trips learners up, but this is a *fundamental* issue, and not restricted to `$`. The same issue comes up when beginners try to assign to computed names, for instance, instead of using vectors (questions that ask how to make `paste0(foo, i) = value` work are extremely frequent). That’s just something they will have to learn, it’s a fundamental concept.

Comment: @J.Mini Yes: partial matching was a stupid, terrible idea that backfired. But see my comment above: you can (**should!**) set an option to make R warn on partial matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base R, my best guess comes from [the documentation for $](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html). The following quotes are the most relevant:

> $ is only valid for recursive objects

> $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. Also, the partial matching behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the exact argument.

> the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from recursive objects (except environments) by $. Even in that case, warnings can be switched on by options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE).

So it seems that the documentation confirms my belief that, aside from partial matching, `$` is just syntactic sugar. However, there are four points where I am unsure:

1. I never put too much faith in R's documentation. Because of this, I'm sure that an experienced user will be able to find a hole in what I've said.
2. I say that this is only my guess for base R because `$` is a generic operator and can therefore have its meaning changed by packages, tibbles being a common example.
3. `$` and `[` can also be used for environments, but I have never seen anyone do so.
4. I don't know what "computed indices" are.

Comment: No, self-answering is absolutely fine, but editing an answer into a question isn’t.

Comment: Can you explain your points 1 and 3? Re 1: the base R documentation is generally of very high quality (compared to other languages), although I’m aware of at least one error in it (and several inconsistencies). And re 3: I don’t understand what you mean … surely `$` is used *far* more often to access names in environments than `[[` (not that either is particularly widespread in most R code …). Re 4: a computed index is a standard-evaluated expression. I.e. the main difference between `[[` and `$`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My point 1 is mostly down to the inconsistencies causing me to lose faith. I'm not confident enough to point out any instances where I'd call R's documentation outright wrong, but there are many times where it feels unhelpful or potentially misleading. As for my point #3, that's more a result of the fact that I rarely if ever seen anyone manipulate environments.

Comment: Ah, I see. For an example of real code using environments (and `$`) extensively, consider my package ‘[box](https://github.com/klmr/box)’, which implements a modern module system for R (packages are venerated but, IMHO, quite flawed).

Answer (score -1):

According to a book on advanced R, the $ and the [ operator are the same on dataframes (not on lists) except from the partial matching. It states

> $ is a shorthand operator: x$y is roughly equivalent to x[["y"]].
> ...The one important difference between $ and [[ is that $ does
> (left-to-right) partial matching:

Here is the quote: Section 4.3.2 of the next link:
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#section-1

Comment: The quoted material is partially correct (but fails to mention the fact that the second argument to $ is not evaluated) but your summary of it is not correct at all, since you refer to a different function as well as failing to mention the lack of evaluation.

Comment: You might have been better off quoting from here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html